# Dynamodb searching/querying GSI with attribute of Item set

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

i am having issues using GSI with attribute that has values of item set, i will appreciate if anyone could direct me on how to solve this problem.
For example i want to query an attribute of
      {"queryStringParameters": {"cities": ["Chicago", "Ikeja", "Victoria 
      Island"]}}

Comment: In order to use query api, you should use partition key to query the index. What is the partition key of GSI?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the point is that i am not using rangeKey to get data that match those values, all i need is a way to query the table with values that has array of object or array of string/number, tho using something like {"state": "Lagos State"} works well for me but using pass array of anything is the nightmare.